# tkinter Text used for user notification

Tags: python, tkinter, concurrency, subprocess

I am fairly new to python and tkinter. I am building a GUI to pipeline a process that uses multiple external .exe programs I want to be able to notify the user that one of those .exe processes has either started or stopped because they can take a long time and I want the user to be able to know where at in the process it currently is.

With my current code the text box update happens all at once at the end of everything rather than after each step. Is there a way to make this update happen at each step or is there a better way that I am unaware of? I am open to the possibility of having a command line open and print to that also.

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as s

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(650,250)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

container = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0)
exe_1_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Process_data_step_1.exe')
exe_2_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Process_data_step_2.exe')
exe_3_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Process_data_step_3.exe')
config_file_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Config.txt')
output_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Output')

def start_processing():
    # notifu user that we are starting to process the data
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Starting to process data for exe1.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update here
    s.check_call([exe_1_path.get(), '-c', config_file_path.get(), 'o', output_path.get])
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Finished processing data for exe1.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Starting to process data for exe2.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    s.check_call([exe_2_path.get(), '-c', config_file_path.get(), 'o', output_path.get])
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Finished processing data for exe2.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Starting to process data for exe3.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    s.check_call([exe_3_path.get(), '-c', config_file_path.get(), 'o', output_path.get])
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Finished processing data for exe3.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here

start_button = tk.Button(container, text='Start', width=10, command = start_processing)
start_button.grid(row = 0, pady=10, padx=20)

output_window = tk.Text(root, height = 10, width = 75, bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
output_window.grid(row = 1, pady=10, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Calling `check_call()` will make your script hang or freeze until it returns. You will need to periodically check on the status of the subprocess and update the GUI accordingly. In order to help you with that, you will need to post a more complete [mre] (MRE).

Comment: You can add `output_window.update_idletasks()` before each `check_call()`.

Comment: @acw1668 wouldn't that still hang tkinter while `check_call` is running? I mean it will be somewhat better than now but freezing will still be a thing

Comment: @Matiiss OP does not ask about freezing issue.

Comment: @acw1668 That is exactly what I was looking for thanks. I am not concerned about tkinter hanging while the subprocess works just wanted a way to notify the user of progress.

Answer (score 0):

To update the text in the output_window use output_window.update()

The example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as s

root = tk.Tk()
root.minsize(650,250)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

container = tk.Frame(root).grid(row=0, column=0)
exe_1_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Process_data_step_1.exe')
exe_2_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Process_data_step_2.exe')
exe_3_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Process_data_step_3.exe')
config_file_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Config.txt')
output_path = tk.StringVar(root, value = 'C:\\Users\\Output')

def start_processing():
    # notifu user that we are starting to process the data
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Starting to process data for exe1.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update here
    s.check_call('python example_subprocess1.py')
    #s.check_call([exe_1_path.get(), '-c', config_file_path.get(), 'o', output_path.get])
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Finished processing data for exe1.\n')
    output_window.update()
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Starting to process data for exe2.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    s.check_call('python example_subprocess1.py')
    #s.check_call([exe_2_path.get(), '-c', config_file_path.get(), 'o', output_path.get])
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Finished processing data for exe2.\n')
    output_window.update()
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Starting to process data for exe3.\n')
    # I want the textbox to update and here
    s.check_call('python example_subprocess1.py')
    #s.check_call([exe_3_path.get(), '-c', config_file_path.get(), 'o', output_path.get])
    output_window.insert(tk.END, 'Finished processing data for exe3.\n')
    output_window.update()
    # I want the textbox to update and here

start_button = tk.Button(container, text='Start', width=10, command = start_processing)
start_button.grid(row = 0, pady=10, padx=20)

output_window = tk.Text(root, height = 10, width = 75, bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
output_window.grid(row = 1, pady=10, padx=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Where the example subprocess (trivial for you already but for others & later use):

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
from tkinter import messagebox

import time

#luodaan kuva...
ikkuna=tkinter.Tk()
ikkuna.title("Example subprocess 1 (here some serial data processing...)")
ikkuna.geometry("800x400")


kanvaasi=Canvas(ikkuna,width=800,height=400)
kanvaasi.pack(fill="both",expand=True)

kanvaasi.create_text(370,80,text="V1")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,130,text="V2")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,180,text="V3")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,220,text="VPack")
kanvaasi.create_text(370,270,text="Capacity")

def read():
    global v1,v2,v3,vpack,capacity
    global kv1,kv2,kv3,kv4,kv5

    #this is only simulation, in real case replace the simulation code with the real one...
    v1=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    v2=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    v3=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    vpack=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    capacity=np.random.random(1)[0].round(decimals=2)
    #...end of simulation

    try:
        kanvaasi.delete(kv1)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv2)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv3)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv4)
        kanvaasi.delete(kv5)
    except:
        pass

    #let's update the tkinter accordingly...
    kv1=kanvaasi.create_text(430,80,text=v1)
    kv2=kanvaasi.create_text(430,130,text=v2)
    kv3=kanvaasi.create_text(430,180,text=v3)
    kv4=kanvaasi.create_text(430,220,text=vpack)
    kv5=kanvaasi.create_text(430,270,text=capacity)

    ikkuna.destroy()


painike1=Button(ikkuna,text="Read",command=read,height=14,width=20)
painike1_ikkuna=kanvaasi.create_window(120,70,anchor="nw",window=painike1)

ikkuna.mainloop()
```